# Swiftlint and swiftformat init configuration

Tags: swift, xcode

I like to have linters and formatter in my IDE. The dilemma started when I began using Xcode. Thanks to tools like [Swiftlint](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint) and [SwiftFormat](https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat) we can fill some missing gaps in Xcode. My question - Is there better method than putting them each time in every project Podfile

```
pod 'SwiftLint' 
pod 'SwiftFormat/CLI'
```

Don't get me wrong, it's not big deal to add this once per project, prepare some pre-commit hook, but maybe there is a better way?

Comment: Create a custom Xcode template that includes the pods by default?

Comment: This sounds Ok, i was thinking that there might be some way to integrate those features directly to Xcode